# Linting for Pug and SASS inside Svelte files

Tags: sass, pug, svelte, lint, stylelint

My current setup is SvelteKit with preprocessors (TypeScript, Pug & SASS). I already have eslint, pug-lint & stylelint in place, but I can't make pug-lint and stylelint work inside .svelte files. These two only works for .pug and .sass files, respectively, outside of .svelte files. Are there any plugins that I need to install or additional configuration to do?

Comment: Wow, got a closing vote but no comments.

Comment: I'm just going to assume that there is no solution for my problem (at the time of posting the question).